# Hacky Haskell monadic testing

Tags: haskell, unit-testing, monads

> **Edit for posterity:** The library you're looking for is [Hspec](http://hspec.github.io/).

I recently started writing Haskell tests with HUnit.
My general setup looks something like this:

```
import Test.HUnit

import Widget (foo, bar)

tests = TestList [ "foo" ~: testFoo
                 , "bar" ~: testBar
                 ]

testFoo :: Test
testFoo = TestList
  [ "with even numbers" ~:
    4 ~=? foo 4
  , "with odd numbers" ~:
    0 ~=? foo 5
  ]

testBar :: Test
testBar = TestList [ {- omitted -} ]
```

The semantics of this are fine with me: I'm trying to do expected–actual testing, not property testing like Quickcheck does.
However, there are two things that I don't like about the syntax:

- the list syntax feels really clunky, and
- I have to write `"foo"` once and `testFoo` two times (three counting the type annotations); while I could inline this, that would make the lists even clunkier.

My goal was to be able to write tests like this:

```
import Test.HUnit (Test, (~=?))
import Describe (toTests, (...), (~:))

import Widget (foo, bar)

tests :: Test
tests = toTests $ do
  "foo" ... do
    "with even numbers" ~:
      4 ~=? foo 4
    "with odd numbers" ~:
      0 ~=? foo 5
  "bar" ... do
    "with true" ~:
      10 ~=? bar True
    "with false" ~:
      -10 ~=? bar False
```

I managed to accomplish just that!
But to do so I had to resort to what I consider to be a pretty ugly monad.
Here's `Describe.hs`:

```
module Describe(group, describe, toTests, (~:), (...)) where

import qualified Test.HUnit as H

data LeftList l r = LeftList [l] ()
                    deriving (Show)

instance Monad (LeftList l) where
  (>>=) = error "LeftList does not support binding; use (>>) instead"
  (LeftList xs a) >> (LeftList ys b) = LeftList (xs ++ ys) b
  return x = LeftList [] ()

group :: String -> LeftList H.Test () -> LeftList H.Test ()
group s (LeftList xs ()) = LeftList [s H.~: xs] ()

(...) = group
infixr 9 ...

describe :: String -> H.Test -> LeftList H.Test ()
describe s x = LeftList [s H.~: x] ()

(~:) = describe
infixr 0 ~:

toTests :: LeftList H.Test () -> H.Test
toTests (LeftList xs _) = H.TestList xs
```

Obviously, the ugly part is creating this data type that has an unnecessary second type parameter and isn't actually a monad!
That is, my implementation of the `do`-notation is incomplete; sequencing works fine, but if I wrote `x <- "foo" ... do { }` I would get the error here.

I don't really mind that I'm shadowing `HUnit.~:`, although it's not optimal.

So, my question: what's the cleanest way to get the desired test case syntax without making the monads cry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would advise you to look at how [blaze-html](http://jaspervdj.be/blaze/tutorial.html) implements their monads for HTML templating. They are doing something very similar to what you want to do.

You can simplify your definitions a bit by removing the second field from the `LeftList` constructor:

```
data LeftList a r = LeftList [a]
```

Then every place where you use the constructor `LeftList` you can omit the (now) extraneous `()`, e.g. the `>>` definition simplifies to:

```
  (LeftList xs) >> (LeftList ys) = LeftList (xs ++ ys)
```

You should also make `group`, `describe`, and `toTests` more general by using a type variable instead of `()`:

```
group :: String -> LeftList H.Test r -> LeftList H.Test r
```

This makes these functions valid for any return type `r` - not just `()`.
Of course, you don't care what the return type is anyway. But GHC cares - and allowing a general return type might help with type checking.

It actually is possible to define bind for the `LeftList` monad -- just pass in `undefined` or `error "..."`:

```
  (>>=) (LeftList xs) f = let LeftList ys = f (error "LeftList does not support binding")
                          in LeftList (xs++ys)
```

An error will occur only if the parameter to `f` is actually evaluated.

For instance, this will not throw an error:

```
"foo" ... do
   x <- "with even numbers" ~:
           4 ~=? foo 4
   "with odd numbers" ~:
     0 ~=? foo 5
```

because the value `x` is never evaluated.

Finally, with GHC 7.10 you will also have to define Functor and Applicative instances for your monad:

```
instance Functor (LeftList a) where
  fmap f left = left

instance Applicative (LeftList a) where
  pure _ = LeftList []  -- should be same as return
  (<*>)  = undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll definitely look at Blaze. But I don't see how `(LeftList xs) >> (LeftList ys) = LeftList (xs ++ ys)` can work. It fails type-check because `(>>)` has specialized signature `LeftList a -> LeftList b -> LeftList b`, so `xs :: [a]` and `ys :: [b]` and we can't `(++)` those. What am I missing?

Comment: Also, [Blaze source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.5.1.4/docs/src/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#MarkupM) for the lazy

Comment: Here's my code: http://lpaste.net/141881

Comment: Ah! You meant to remove the second field from the *constructor*, not the *type*. Reading more carefully, that's exactly what you said. Got it.

Comment: Great, this feels a bit better! I'll leave this question open for a bit to encourage more feedback. Thank you!